# Sorting list in replacing in a specific order

Tags: apex, rest

I need to sort a list in a specific order which is been provided from list wrapper coming prepared from custom setting.Final Wrapper and class includes the below code.

```
    global class vision {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Boolean Editable { get; set; }
        public Boolean Required { get; set; }
        public String Field { get; set; }

        public map <String, List <String>> PickVal { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to have `List<Vision>` values in a specific order other than the one coming from custom setting.

Is there any way other than iterating and then creating new.

I have used the same However , Seems I need to define constructor in my below code. :

```
           List <vision> Vcloud = new List <vision> ();

            Map<String,visionValue__c> cs =visionValue__c.getAll();
            List<String> keys = new List<String>(cs.keySet());
            keys.sort();
            for (String key : keys) {
                visionValue__c Value = cs.get(key);
                vision Fieldvcloud = new Division();
                   if (Value.Division__c == 'AI') {
                    Fieldvcloud.SortVal=DivValue.Sort__c;
                    Vcloud.add(DivFieldvcloud);
                    }
                     }
```

How to pass value in contructor in this case?As I am getting Message: Argument cannot be null. in the rest api call seems reason is value not been set

Comment: After reading your comment on my answer, and your edited question, I have no idea what you're talking about. At any rate, though, this is sounding like you should create a new question (with a better explanation and more details)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what the [Comparable Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm) is for.

You'd have your `Vision` class implement the interface (i.e. `global class Vision implements Comparable{...`), and then provide an implementation of the `compareTo(Object compareAgainstObj)` method. After implementing it, you can use `list.sort()` to sort your list items.

A basic implementation might look like

```
public Integer compareTo(Object compareAgainstObj){
    // Re-cast the argument so you can access its class variables/properties
    Vision compareAgainst = (Vision)compareAgainstObj;

    // You can have multiple levels of tests before returning a result
    if(this.name.toLower() == compareAgainst.name.toLower()){
        if(this.Editable == compareAgainst.Editable){
            // Name is equal (case-insensitive), and Editable is equal.
            // That's equal enough for this demo
            return 0;
        }else{
            // Name is equal (case-insensitive), but Editable is not.
            // Let's say that 'true' comes before 'false'
            if(this.Editable){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }else{
        // Name is not equal, even case-insenstive.
        // Just use standard string ordering here.
        // This would return 1 if this.name lexicographically precedes compareAgainst.name
        return compareAgainst.name.compareTo(this.name);
    }
}
```

Adjust as needed to suit your sorting requirements.

Comment: Ah.  beat me to it.

Comment: I am unable to pass value through contructor, As I am using class and property to set the value